# Gracefully remove "\n" delimiter after last String within StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, newline, stringbuilder

Have following Java code,that creates `StringBuilder` with "\n",i.e. carriage return delimiters:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    sb.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
}
```

It's occurred,that after last String(line) had "\n" symbol.

How to gracefully remove last "\n" from resulting `StringBuilder` object?

thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has always worked for me

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
```

Operation is pretty lightweight, internal value holding current content size will just be decreased by 1.

Also, check length value before doing it if you think buffer may be empty.

Comment: This approach is interesting, although the length check later on seems a downside.

Comment: @cherouvim Yep. On the other hand, you don't allocate unnecessary memory, like with 'trim' or 'join'. Although, your answer is pretty good too, I often use that approach myself.

Comment: In extremely high performance situations where I'd have to add millions of elements on sb I'd definitelly use your approach since it has the quickest loop (no if check).

Comment: The length call will likely be replaced with a direct variable lookup at runtime...  and the check for length == 0 after only happens once, unlike other solutions where an if is done each iteration of the loop.  So no real downsides compared to other ways.

Comment: in Windows this delete only 0A char, but you still have 0D at the end

Comment: To be "more robust" you can use System.Environment.NewLine.Length to remove the system's newline string.

Answer (score 13):

If you're working with a small enough number of lines, you can put all the lines in a `List<String>` and then use [`StringUtils.join(myList, "\n");`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29)

Another option is to `trim()` the resulting string.

#### Update after discovering guava's neat [`Joiner`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/guava/guava/r09/guava-r09-javadoc.jar!/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#on%28char%29) class:

`Joiner.on('\n').join(myList)`

Comment: +1 better than mine, assuming the `List<String>` can be known / stored reasonably.

Comment: actually, can't find method join for StringUtils(that is sringframework class)

Comment: Sorry that was unclear, I was referring to the apache commons-lang library. I put the link in the answer.

Comment: ok, now i see,its' apache lib, unfortunately we don't have in our project

Answer (score 4):

You could build the result without a newline to get rid of:

```
String separator = "";
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    sb.append(separator).append(scanner.nextLine());
    separator = "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having to remove it you could simply never add it.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    if (sb.length()>0) sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly if one or more lines at the beginning are blank.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isFirst = true;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
  if(!isFirst)
    sb.append("\n"));
  else
    isFirst = false;

  sb.append(scanner.nextLine());

}
```

Comment: neat way of getting rid of `else isFirst = false;`: `if (!isFirst | (isFirst = false))`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
  sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
  sb.append("\n").append(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: The problem here is the code duplication for appending. In this example it's trivial, but in other cases it may be not. So duplicating is not good.

Comment: Agreed.  I think the `trim()` solution is inelegant, and mine suffers from code duplication.  Maybe `join()` is the best...